# jQuery `.find()` not finding elements that "match this selector"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the jQuery doc for the `find` function, it states

> The elements will be filtered by testing whether they match this
>   selector

But it appears that this isn't strictly accurate, or I'm making an incorrect assumption about what this sentence means. If this was correct, I would expect the following to make the background of my `p` element green, but it's leaving it red.

```js
$('#banner-message').find('p').css('background-color', 'red');

document.getElementById('banner-message').querySelectorAll('#parent p')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; // but this works?

// $('#parent #banner-message').find('p').css('background-color', 'green'); // does what's expected
$('#banner-message').find('#parent p').css('background-color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="banner-message">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Clearly the `p` element matches the selector I'm giving it, but it almost seems as though the originating element prefixes the selector, which isn't stated anywhere in the documentation.

So is this a bug with jQuery? Or am I incorrect in my interpretation of how `.find()` is supposed to work?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193432/discussion-on-question-by-brian-leishman-jquery-find-not-finding-elements-t).

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` looks for decendants from the currently selected element. In pseudocode, you're saying:

> Find the element with the ID `banner-message`
>   THEN search for a child with the ID `parent` and then search again for a `p` element
>   Change the background-colour to green

If you're wanting to find elements form parent then you cannot call this from `$('#banner-message')` however you could do `$('#parent').find('p').css('background-color', 'green');`

Comment: I could also do `$('#banner-message').find('*').filter(function () { return $(this).is('#parent p') }).css('background-color', 'green')` like I said in one of my comments

Comment: @BrianLeishman  `is()` is not the same operation as `find()`.  `find()` is a traversal method.  `is()` is a matching method.  `find()` requires the selector to match the DOM subtree under the element you are selecting on.  `is()` is checking if the element matches the selector in the **entire** DOM tree.